# Is there a distinct value in collection of sets

Tags: algorithm, set

I have N sets of values, eg.

- S1 = {A,B,C,D,E}
- S2 = {A,B,C,D,E,F}
- S3 = {A,B}
- S4 = {C,E,F,G,H}

I wish to know is if there is a distinct or unique value in each set of the collection... Ie. is there a 'path' through the sets that leaves at least one value in each set that is not in any other..
The answer to the example above would be TRUE as you could have :
B from S1, D from S2, A from S3 and C from S4

A FALSE example would be:

- S1 = {A,B,C}
- S2 = {A}
- S3 = {A,B}
- S4 = {A,C}

As values would need to be duplicated between sets.

As always, I am certain there must be a trivial solution to this problem. Any help would be very gratefully received. Thank you

**Clarification**

Thanks for the answers so far but I am still slightly confused by this, albeit having what is (I think) a *simple* requirement. I suspect I made the question sound more confusing than the problem it actually represents.

To clarify, my end goal is to:

- Have a single value from each set.
- This list of new values should be distinct from one another.
- The value picked from each set is relatively arbritrary.
- If a single distinct value cannot be derived from the input sets then the process should return nothing

I have read about Bipartite graphs and maximum flow but I cant quite see the 'wood from the trees' Ultimately I need to write some code in .NET to implement this, so some pseudo code would be a really big help, if thats not possible just a simpler example of the relevant algorthm in action would be great.

Comment: Do you know if the values in the sets are bound in some way? E.g. if they are letters in the English alphabet, then there are only 26 possible values.

Comment: Jacob, no they are GUIDs and have no bounds. There can also be an unlimited amount (although likely less than 50)

Comment: It's really unclear what your question is based on your response to Adam. Is it that you want to remove one element such that once the elements are removed, each set contains a unique element?

Comment: I thought I had expanded on the original post, I obviously made it more complex, sorry. In the first example, take a pencil and draw a line through B, D, A and C down from S1 down to S4. For any given values in any number of sets, I wish to know if (at least one) such line can be drawn. I could test every combination, but this sounds expensive and I think there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a bipartite graph with ;

```
Set X containing value of nodes = {S1,S2,S3,...,SN}
Set Y containing value of nodes = {A,B,C...}
```

Match this graph to the problem statement by making edges as per the sets given in the problem.

The problem reduces to checking if the "**maximum (bipartite) matching**" between X and Y is equal to N. If the assignment of values needs to known, then print this matching as well.

EDIT (for more explanation)

[image]

The edges between the two sets denote the original sets. We need to find edges such that all vertices in X are covered and no 2 edges  share a common vertex

Note: Multiple maximum matching may exist

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply to this problem, I appreciate it. However if all of the Y values are in the new set together, what differentiates them and binds them back to their original set?

Comment: @NickWilliams, I have edited the post. Hope its more helpful now. To answer your query specifically, it is **edges** which bind them back to their original set

Comment: Thats great thankyou. All I have to do now is implement this in code.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* your requirement is this:

Call the sets `S1`, `S2`, ..., `Sn`. Call the elements `a1`, `a2`, ..., `am`. Then you want to:

- for each `S`, **pick** a member `a` of `S` such that there is at least one other `S` that does *not* contain that `a`

So in your example:

- `S1` **picks** `B` (which is absent from `S4`)
- `S2` **picks** `D` (which is absent from `S3`)
- `S3` **picks** `A` (which is absent from `S4`)
- `S4` **picks** `C` (which is absent from `S3`)

To solve this, a possible approach is:

- Iterate through the `S`s and member `a`s, keeping track of all the distinct `a`s seen along with a count of how many `S`s they appear in
- Iterate through the `S`s again, and for each, look at the constructed count list for a member `a` with a count less than `n`, the total number of `S`s. **Pick** an arbitrary `a` that meets this requirement

And we're done.

---

There appears to be an additional requirement from your comment "if 'A' exists in more than one set, then 'A' should be left in one of the sets", that

- for each `a` that is a member of more than one `S`, that `a` is the '**picked**' member of some `S`

**However**, I can't see how to square your comment with the fact that in your example, `E` exists in more than one `S`, but is never **picked**.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you for your time. I will write some code tomorrow to test this approach. Re your last comment, I don't need E to necessarily ever get picked unless it is the only distinct A in that set, amongst all the other Sets. Ultimately I only need to select a single arbitrary item from each set that is distinct from the others. Any combination will do! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's represent data from your first example in the form of a table:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
s1  .   .   .   .   .
s2  .   .   .   .   .   .
s3  .   .
s4          .       .   .   .   .
```

Now, we are looking for some solution, for example this one (taken from the question):

```
s1=b, s2=d, s3=a, s4=c
```

Marked solution (there cannot be two X in one column):

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h
s1  .   X   .   .   .
s2  .   .   .   X   .   .
s3  X   .
s4          X       .   .   .   .
```

It's similar to choosing a task for a processor in [Assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)...

But if you don't care about complexity, how about checking all possible configurations?

```
for (every element in s1) as e1
    for (every element in s2) as e2
        for (every element in s3) as e3
            for (every element in s4) as e4
                if (e1 != e2 != e3 != e4)
                    return true;
return false;
```

It's trivial brute force with complexity `O(s1.length * s2.length * s3.length * s4.length)`.

Comment: There can be more than one X per column. Duplicate values per se are allowed as long as there is a path of non duplicate values through the sets. I am not looking to test a particular solution as long as I can tell that there is a general solution to any given values of sets. I almost need to sieve each set to leave the values that don't exist in other sets. However (and it may not have been clear in my original post) if 'A' exists in more than one set, then 'A' should be left in one of the sets. Then, once the sets are 'sieved' I can say that if each set has > 0 item(s) the result is TRUE